# unset multiple arrays elements based on position

Tags: php, arrays, json, unset

I'm trying to remove objects from an array based on their position
I'm saving the positions in an array: **$items**.
And my main array: **$array**

```
<?php       $items = $_POST['items'];
    $winkelkar = json_encode($_SESSION['winkelkar']);
    $array = json_decode( $winkelkar, true );
    $aantalItems = count($items)-1;
    for($i=$aantalItems;$i>=0;$i--){
        unset($array[$items[$i]]);
    }
    $array = array_values($array);
    $_SESSION['winkelkar'] = $array;
    echo json_encode($array);?>
```

I'm looping over the array and removing the objects I don't want.
It works perfectly with one item, or if I remove more starting from the end of the array.
But if I start of with

> **$array=[{"aantal":"2","id":"21"},{"aantal":"1","id":"96"},{"aantal":"1","id":"97","optie":"24"},{"aantal":"1","id":"2"},{"aantal":"1","id":"75"}]**

And i want to remove, let's say: **$items=(0,2,4);** It removes other object than intended and returns:

> **[{"aantal":"1","id":"75"}]**

What am I doing wrong?
If you need more parts of my code, feel free to ask!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There where I was filling my **$items** array, i didn't end my loop causing the loop to execute my ajax-call multiple times.

Debugging did the trick.